# Validating number using Ruby Regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation

Working on a Rails project that requires me to validate a number (representing a day of the month) as either 1 or 15. I placed the following validation at the top of my model:

```
validates :deposit_date, presence: true, format: { with: /\A1(5)?\z/ }
```

The regex works as intended when I use irb or online testers, but fails validation in the Rails app. The number is being passed as a string, so I don't think it's a type issue.

Update: Thank you for all of the relevent answers so quickly. I was able to track down the issue... data in the DB was already invalid, causing a seperate save! call to fail ;)

Comment: Are you sure `deposit_date` is a String representing only the day of the month and not a `Date`-type class, or at least a String representing the date, e.g., `'2014-03-24'`? Both of those would not match that regex.

Comment: Yes, it is either the number 1 or 15.. the values are coming from an HTML select field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the capture of the 5.

```
{ with: /\A15?\z/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
 validates :deposit_date, inclusion: { in: [1,15] }

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
validates :deposit_date, presence: true, format: { with: /\A15?/ }
```

`\z` will match end of the string. In your case you just need to match the day(start of the string).